# Can we make the content in div tags invisible on Page Load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

```
<div class="reusableBlueContent">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 500px;">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" style="height: 24px;">
        <h3 style="text-align: left; height: 23px;">
           Package Recap</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

I have something like this. I want to make "Package Recap" invisible when the page is loaded. It is in the . Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

in your .aspx markup:

```
<div id="DivServerControl" runat="server" class="reusableBlueContent"> some stuff </div>
```

in your code behind:

```
protected override void OnLoad(Object sender)
{
     DivServerControl.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: just put runat="server" and id="SOMEID" on whatever element you want to hide